# Compare values between array and object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I am using Angular and Lodash for working with objects and arrays.

Given this:

```
$scope.week = ['monday','tuestday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday']
$scope.points = [
    { day: 'monday', points: 30 },
    { day: 'wednesday', points: 60 }
]
```

...I want to get this result :

```
$scope.result = [30, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

So I have to compare an array with an object, but I want to avoid the use of multiple loops.

See [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/queztal/6sacorLu/).

P.S: I don't use jQuery.

Comment: A link to a fiddle is fine, but please put that code inside your question as well.

Comment: Ok, so, you want to compare X and Y, where X and Y are two different types of structures. What exactly are you trying to compare between them? What are the two source structures and what result do you want from the comparison of said two source structures? seems you may be able to remove angular from the equation and provide a sample that is just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var temp = $scope.points.reduce((obj, el) => (obj[el.day] = el.points, obj), {});
$scope.result = $scope.week.map(day => temp[day] || 0);
```

The **temp** variable is an object that is keyed by day and provides as value the points linked to that day. Given the example data it would look like:

```
{
    monday: 30,
    wednesday: 60
}
```

It allows for efficient lookup in the second statement.

See [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sacorLu/2/)

NB: make sure to correct that spelling error in your week array ('tuestday').

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.map and _.findIndex metho of lodash or simple Array class as below

```
$scope.result =_.map($scope.week, function (v, i) {
    var index = _.findIndex($scope.points, { 'day': v})
    if (index > -1) {
        return $scope.points[index].points
    } else {
        return 0
    }
})
```

Where _ is an instance of lodash.

Answer (score -1):

In case of your data structure, you can use Javascript array methods, like this:

```
var filteredPoints = $scope.points.filter((point) => {
      return $scope.week.indexOf(point.day) != -1;
     });

$scope.result = filteredPoints.map((point) => { return point.points });
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but running this code gives me an array with 1 element.

Comment: My predicate was missing a condition, it is now updated